# display: inline-block vs display: table (no display: table-cell)

Tags: html, css

I have used both of the `display` properties whenever **I wanted the width of an element to be the same as its content**.

**But is one better than the other?** I'm referring to accessibility, browser compatibility, responsiveness, etc.

**Note:** I am asking because I'm planing to use only one of these in my new web site. I just don't know which one is better, if any.

Comment: If you're making a table, then probably use `table`. I think `display:inline-block` would be preferable for other use cases

Comment: Why do you want to limit the site to using one or the other? Use what what makes sense in each case.

Comment: Which one make sense in which cases?

Comment: simply read the documentation and understand how each one behave then you will get the cases .. it's like you ask about difference between padding and margin : both add space but not in the same way

Comment: Did you mean `display: inline-block` vs `display: table-cell`?

Comment: No, I meant `display: table`, no `cell` in it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ultimately, it depends on the use case:

- `display: inline-block` will create an `inline-block` element
- `display: table` will create a `table` element

Here they are in use:

```css
span.mySpan {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>A span element.</span>
  <span class="mySpan" style="display: table;">a <code>display: table</code> element.</span>
  <span>Another span element.</span>
</div>

<br/>
<br/>

<div>
  <span>A span element.</span>
  <span class="mySpan" style="display: inline-block;">a <code>display: inline-block</code> element.</span>
  <span>Another span element.</span>
</div>
```

As can be seen, the results are very different. The `table` element positions itself on a new line, and causes the next element to be on a new line as well. The `inline-block` element positions itself inline with it's sibling elements.

In many cases, the above differences will be enough to choose one or the other.

If not, let's continue...

There are some cases when `display: table` is useful:

- Horizontal and vertical centering of elements
- Equal height elements

However, browsers can produce inconsistent results when not implemented correctly so you should always couple `display: table` with the standard table markup (using rows and cells):

```css
.table {
  display: table;
}

.table-row {
  display: table-row:
}

.table-cell {
  display: table-cell;
  background-color: #eaeaea;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="table-row">
    <div class="table-cell">
      Content
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell"  style="height: 100px;">
      Content
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      Content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This becomes pretty tedious. And with modern CSS we can accomplish the same using `display: flex`, with a simpler HTML structure and less CSS:

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.flex-cell {
  background-color: #eaeaea;
  padding: 10px; 
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="flex-cell">
    Content
  </div>
  <div class="flex-cell" style="height: 100px;">
    Content
  </div>
  <div class="flex-cell">
    Content
  </div>
</div>
```

Honestly, I can't think of many times I would need to decide between `display: inline-block` and `display: table` as they produce such different results. However, if I were on the fence I'd follow this decision tree:

1. Do I need to make a table? Use a true `<table></table>` element
2. Do I need equal height/width elements, and/or vertical centering? Use a `display: flex` element
3. Otherwise, use the appropriate HTML element (`display: inline-block`)

Comment: Man, that is great! Thank you. One question. In your code, you put the `display:table-cell` inside a `display:table-row`. I edited it and put the `display:table-cell` *directly( under the `display:table` (deleting the entire table-row) and it renders the same. The table-row is necessary, since I am getting the same result?

Comment: The `table-row` and even the `table` aren't necessary. It's the `table-cell` elements doing all the work in that case. But keep in mind browsers produce inconsistent results using that markup.

Comment: "browsers can produce inconsistent results when not implemented correctly" I call FUD. Can you name a browser that gets this wrong? And especially one that gets it wrong yet implements flexbox.

Comment: I have come across a situation where some information made the most sense visually if displayed as a table, but it wasn't _tabular data_ — semantically it was not a table, but it was visually easier to comprehend. In that one case I used `display:table` and `table-row` & `table-cell`. In _all other_ cases go with Brett's answer - if it's a table make it a `<table>` otherwise don't. IMHO using `display:table` breaks the _"don't use tables for layout"_ rule.

Comment: @StephenP  - No it doesn't. The reason for the "don't use tables for layout" rule is that HTML tables are reported through accessiblity technology with descriptions of rows and columns that are confusing to their users if the contents of the cells are not tabular data. That doesn't happen with a div element with `display:table`.

Comment: @Alohci - What specifically are you referring to when you say 'name a browser that gets this wrong?'

Comment: @BrettDeWoody - A browser that implements `display:table` incorrectly such that it produces inconsistent results. Clearly IE6, say, didn't implement `display:table` *at all*, but what it did do was to ignore it consistently. Furthermore, flexbox would not provide a better solution for such a browser.

Comment: @Alohci - I'd love to be wrong here. And honestly, I'm not an expert in this area. But I was able to find an example which behaves inconsistently in Chrome (mac) v63 and Firefox (mac) v57 - http://jsfiddle.net/wvg8n/. When a `table-cell` element is added they behave consistently.

Comment: @BrettDeWoody - Thanks for that. Unfortunately I don't have a mac to test on, and on Windows they look the same. Can you describe briefly what happens in Chrome vs Firefox, please?

Comment: @Alohci - point taken and you're definitely right about the a11y differences, yet I've never had a need to use `display:table` because (again my opinion) there are better options including flex, and now grid.

Comment: @Alohci - Hovering over parts of the `<li>` element don't cause the `:hover` state to be triggered. Chrome on the left, Firefox on the right - https://imgur.com/o7X6ZjW